# HTML/CSS Span Tag causing Bootstrap Modal Footer buttons to lower

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

On my website I used a span tag to pull a button and a text input left from the footer of a twitter bootstrap modal display, the pictures will show this.

For some reason the two buttons on the left and lower than the two on the right, how can I raise the two on the left?
HTML:

CSS:

```
.modal-footer .floatLeft {
    float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <span class="floatLeft">
        <input placeholder="out of" class='changeMaxMark' style='margin-top:9px;'id='maxMarkBox' name='maxMarkBox' type='text'>
        <button  id='changeMaxMark' name='changeMaxMark' class='btn btn-success'> Set All </button>
    </span>
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="markSave" onClick="togleMarkSave()">Save Changes</button>
</div>
```

link to picture 1(http://snag.gy/i5FRT.jpg)
link to picture 2(http://snag.gy/2Y9Q2.jpg)

Comment: Can you please post a fiddle of that section of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all remove the span.  Bootstrap has specific CSS classes to pull things left. `pull-left` which I added to the first two elements.

The edited HTML is this:

```
<div class="modal-footer">    
    <input placeholder="out of" class='changeMaxMark pull-left' id='maxMarkBox' name='maxMarkBox' type='text'>
    <button  id='changeMaxMark' name='changeMaxMark' class='btn btn-success  pull-left'> Set All </button>
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="markSave" onClick="togleMarkSave()">Save Changes</button>
</div>
```

You also had a specific style on the input field to push margin-top down 9px that is unecessary.

No custom CSS classes or additional markup is necessary.

Here is the working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DhE6U/1/)